# Java NIO UserDefinedFileAttributeView written values not available across platform

Tags: java, file, io, nio

I am trying to write a User Defined file attribute to a file. But it will be available in only platform where it is written.
Here is code sample:

```
UserDefinedFileAttributeView userView=Files.getFileAttributeView(file.toPath(), UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
        ByteBuffer buffer= ByteBuffer.allocate(userView.size("Version"));
        userView.read("Version", buffer);
```

If write property in Windows and try to read in linux then it wont avaible and vice versa

Is this expected ? Is there any way to achieve cross platform file metadata ?

Any help is appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Those file attributes are filesystem specific and not stored as part of a file. So you cannot exchange them with the file between different operating systems. You will find on the link further information about [Extended File Attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes).

Comment: @SubOptimal Thanks for reply. Is there any way i can set the version of the file ? across the platform ?

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve. If the file format itself does not provide version information and you need to exchange the file between different OS/file systems you could only provide it within an additional file. Or similar.